# each in jquery after append

Tags: jquery, append, each

I see now I was copy pasting the wrong text/question, that didn't make sense at all! Sorry for that! I found the error in my code. Here is a working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
}
#gallery{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
background:#000;
opacity:0.9;
}
.child{
width:auto;
height:auto;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="click_me">click me</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#click_me').click(function(){
$('body').append('<div id="gallery"></div><div class="child" style="width:300px;height:600px;background:#0F0"></div><div class="child" style="width:500px;height:400px;background:#C60"></div><div class="child" style="width:600px;height:200px;background:#390"></div>');
   height_of_window = $('#gallery').height();
   width_of_window = $('#gallery').width();
   max_height = height_of_window - 100;
   max_width = width_of_window - 100;
   $('.child').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      height_of_child = $this.height();
      width_of_child = $this.width();
      if (width_of_child >= max_width) {
         $this.css({
            'max-width': max_width + 'px'
         })
      }
      if (height_of_child >= max_height) {
         $this.css({
            'max-height': max_height + 'px'
         })
      }
      margin_top = (height_of_window - $this.height()) / 2;
      margin_left = (width_of_window - $this.width()) / 2;
      $this.css({
         'margin-top': margin_top + 'px',
         'margin-left': margin_left + 'px'
      })
   }); // end click
   }); // end each
}); // end document redy
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You haven't told us what the problem is, but:</s>

You've said that the code works *(if so, it won't be reliable; see below)* if you put the markup in the HTML, but not if you append that markup using code. The code you've quoted will not have that problem because it shows clearly that you're appending and then doing the search for ".image" elements, but you need to be sure that you **do** do the append **before** you run the other code, and you need to do these things once the `body` tag is ready to have things appended to it. Either make sure your script is at the very end, just after (or before) the closing `</body>` tag, or use the jQuery [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) function (or its [shortcut](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)).

Separately:

jQuery's `css` function does not support shorthand properties, although they work on some browsers. Per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: `$(elem).css('marginTop')` and `$(elem).css('marginRight')`, and so on.

So this line:

```
$(this).css({'margin':margin_top+'px 0 0 '+ margin_left +'px'})
```

Should be

```
$(this).css({
    marginTop:    margin_top  + 'px',
    marginLeft:   margin_left + 'px',
    marginRight:  "0px",
    marginBottom: "0px"
});
```

Separately, note that ***every time*** you do `$(this)`, it requires several function calls and memory allocations. It's best practice not to repeat it unnecessarily; although it's usually harmless, it creates unnecessary memory churn. Just put `var $this = $(this);` at the beginning of your function and then use `$this` throughout (or whatever else you want to call it). (One gotcha there: Be sure to remember that `this` changes [potentially] in every function, so if you're setting up event handlers, don't use the outer function's `$this` where you mean to use the event handler's version.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that "shorthand properties" only work in some browsers! Didn't know that...

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap this code with

```
$(function() {

    });
```

so that it will load the body first before running the jquery code.  Also make sure that max_width and max_height are set as in this code they are not set.